# How to find in which points both partial derivatives are equal to zero?

Tags: calculus, partial-derivative

I need to find points in which both partial derivatives are equal to zero. 
Partial derivative with respect to $x$ is equal to: $(1-x)ye^{-x-y^2}$
With respect to $y$: $(1-2y^2)xe^{-x-y^2}$

When I set both of them equal to zero, I get from the first equation $y=0$, $x=1$
and from the second $x=0$ and $y=\pm 1/\sqrt 2$.
But this seems that I am not on the right track.

Would be grateful for any tips. Thank you!

Comment: The conditions you get from each partial derivative are alternatives, from the first, you get $y = 0$ __or__ $x = 1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since
$$(1-x)ye^{-x-y^2}=0\Rightarrow x=1\ \text{or}\ y=0,$$
$$ (1-2y^2)xe^{-x-y^2}=0\Rightarrow x=0\ \text{or}\ y=1/\sqrt{2}\ \text{or}\ y=-1/\sqrt 2,$$
you'll have
$$(1-x)ye^{-x-y^2}=0\ \text{and}\ (1-2y^2)xe^{-x-y^2}=0\Rightarrow (x,y)=(0,0),(1,\pm 1/\sqrt 2).$$

**Edit** : You have $2\times 3=6$ possibilities as the followings (Note that 'or' and 'and'):

$$x=1\ \text{and}\ x=0,$$
$$x=1\ \text{and}\ y=1/\sqrt 2,$$
$$x=1\ \text{and}\ y=-1/\sqrt 2,$$
$$y=0\ \text{and}\ x=0,$$
$$y=0\ \text{and}\ y=1/\sqrt 2,$$
$$y=0\ \text{and}\ y=-1/\sqrt 2.$$

You'll see some of these have to be excluded.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! Could you be so kind to explain how you get from having roots of the equations to finding the points?

Comment: @javaniewbie: I added a bit. I hope this helps.

Comment: mathlove, you rock! I got it! Thank you very much!

Comment: You are welcome!